# How to run rust tests with backtrace in vscode on Linux?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, rust, backtrace

Using VSCode on Linux, how can I run `cargo test` with a backtrace?

Answer (score 0):

Open the menu item at `Terminal | Configure Default Build Task` and add an entry to the JSON configuration file as follows:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo test",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$rustc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "label": "cargo test with backtrace"
        }
    ]
}
```